# GNU Parallel: How to unquote `;` so can run multiple commands?

Tags: quotes, gnu-parallel, single-quotes, unquoting

How do I run multiple commands with the `--quote`/`-q` option?

For example, this quotes the `;`:

```bash
$ parallel --dry-run -q command1 {1} \; command2 ::: "With a space" "Another space" "Yet more spaces" "WithoutASpace" 
command1 'With a space' ';' command2
command1 'Another space' ';' command2
command1 'Yet more spaces' ';' command2
```

¿How do I unquote it so that it runs:

```bash
command1 'With a space' ; command2
command1 'Another space' ; command2
command1 'Yet more spaces' ; command2
```

<sup>I know my MWE here probably doesn't need `-q`, but when I have more complicated commands with arguments that need quotes, I ran into the issue that single quotes Parallel put were "leaking" through into the text passed to the command.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already given the solution: remove -q, and addressed the problem, that this raises:

> when I have more complicated commands

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#quoting says:

> Conclusion: If this is confusing consider avoiding having to deal with quoting by writing a small script or a function (remember to export -f the function) and have GNU parallel call that.

You can still use GNU Parallel to generate the arguments.

So:

```
doit() {
  echo "$1" "$2" "$3"
  # You can put comments in the code
  echo do complex stuff here
}
export -f doit
parallel doit {1/} {1.} {2} ::: */* ::: "double  space" "triple   space" "    4 spc"
```

IMHO it often improves readability, too.